# I can't suggest edits on Science Fiction SE

Tags: support, suggested-edits

The link to suggest an edit isn't available to me on Science Fiction & Fantasy (but is available on other sites). Since there is no thorough documentation on how suggested edits work, it's hard to tell whether it's a bug or an aspect of the feature I'm unaware of — hence the [support](/questions/tagged/support) tag.

I know one of my recent suggested edits to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1802/how-does-the-holodeck-create-the-illusion-of-distance) has been rejected, but is one rejected edit enough?

Comment: also bear in mind that *anonymous* suggested edits only work on posts > 12 hours old.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The suggested edits queue only allows a certain number of edits before it will prevent more from being added.  In this case, SciFi's queue was full.  I've gone through and cleaned it up so the system should accept suggested edits again.

For a more complete listing of the details of the suggested edits system, see [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-does-peer-review-for-edits-work/76284#76284).