# For new sites, lower accept edit bar, or raise suggest edit bar

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, voting, suggested-edits

This question:

[I can't suggest edits on Science Fiction SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79227/i-cant-suggest-edits-on-science-ficion-se)

Suggests that there's a high likelihood of filling the suggest edit queue frequently when there aren't enough high rep users to single click accept, or two vote accept edit suggestions.

The balance of high rep users to people who can suggest edits is too heavily weighted towards the lower end.

It may be worthwhile to consider lowering the single click accept and two vote accept edit feature significantly  until a certain percentage of active users can do so.

Other options might include throwing away suggested edits after a period of time, and alerting authors of questions using the supcollider drop down that they can single click accept edits.

Comment: also remember that the concept of multiple votes to accept **exists only on Stack Overflow** and no other site.

Comment: completed in spirit, since the queue is larger. It is RARELY a problem in practice.

Answer (score 1):

No -- in this case **there are no diamond moderators on the site yet**, and that's the limiting factor.

Compare:

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/about

versus

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/about

that said, Sam set the queue max default to what I consider to be a very low value of 10, so I am doubling it to 20.