# Account is Not Allowed to Suggest Edits

Tags: support, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)
>   [Why is the edit button disabled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-is-the-edit-button-disabled)

For some odd reason, I am not allowed to suggest edits ... Why is that?

This is on the main Unix & Linux site.

I haven't done many edits today, as I have just started looking at other people's questions now.

I see this could be related to this, previously reported, question: [I can't suggest edits on Science Fiction SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79227/i-cant-suggest-edits-on-science-fiction-se)

If it is the case, could someone clear up the suggested edits que, please?

Comment: You have quite a number of suggested edits rejected recently - you are banned from suggesting edit for 1 week - IIRC.

Comment: Why is it a duplicate? I can't even click the button ... The edit button is completely grayed out.

Comment: It's a dupe as it (now) kind of answers it. On Meta, we like to keep the answers of FAQs in one place. No worries.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You made quite a few edits yesterday, mostly wiki tag edits, and were rejected:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/2250
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/2251
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/2249
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/2248
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/2247
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/2246

From the rejected reason, you copied content from Wikipedia without attribution. I have cross checked and the decision of the moderator was correct. If you make a large number of suggested edits and were rejected, you will be banned from suggesting edit for 1 week.

Quoted from the post [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work):

> ### What about abuse?
>
> There are strict limits enforced. If a user (anonymous or registered) submits many rejected edits they will be automatically banned from suggesting edits for 7 days. The fixed size queue also helps protect us from abuse.

Comment: Well, @Kevdog, maybe embarrassing, but above all: too bad it was not obvious for you where to see rejected suggestions. You might want to give [Decision on rejected edits should be displayed as a notification to the editor](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor) some love (an upvote)!

Comment: Thanks, I now can see if they are rejected or approved in my Profile.

Comment: And, @Kevdog, note that often hovering your mouse over links, numbers, dates, and what have you, will reveal more details. Just like with the disabled edit link you saw. For future reference, can you tell us what the exact text of that tooltip is? (See [Always show the edit button on questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91172/always-show-the-edit-button-on-questions/138944#138944) And in case you did not see it yet: [When account is not allowed to suggest edits, add a link to the relevant faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/140942/) might like an upvote too.)

Comment: @Arjan: It says exactly: `Account is not allowed to suggest edits` - it doesn't say that I have been banned though. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Wow, @Kevdog, that tooltip is hardly an explanation... Thanks!

Comment: I have 28 edit suggestions approved, and 17 edit suggestions rejected. Many rejected because only delete thanks in edit. (Reject :  This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post.)

Now, my Account is not allowed to suggest edits (banned for 7 days I hope).

But I have seen this:

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Can I delete Thanks and salutations from posts?

Comment: @Kiquenet: Yes, you can. But if the edit only address thanks and salutation, then you should reject it, or edit and uncheck helpful checkbox.