# When account is not allowed to suggest edits, add a link to the relevant FAQ

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, edit-ban

When a user is [getting banned from suggesting edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78129/is-there-a-penalty-for-ones-edit-suggestion-being-rejected/78192#78192) he/she will have just a generic message telling they can't suggest edits anymore. It's really not trivial why this happened.

Same way that a question ban message contains a link to the relevant FAQ here on Meta Stack Overflow, it will be just proper to add a link to the [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) FAQ when a user get the suggested edits ban and try to suggest an edit.

This will render [such questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140936/account-is-not-allowed-to-suggest-edits) "obsolete", and I think I have seen a steady increase in their volume lately.

Comment: I am positive for the link being added, but I fear it would not decrease the number of questions about suggested edits not being accepted anymore, in the same way there are still questions about question bans.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I disagree. For one, the user in [this example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140936/account-is-not-allowed-to-suggest-edits) looks like a reasonable person and I'm almost sure that if a link would have been present, he wouldn't have posted in Meta. Keep in mind that those suggesting edits are not the random newbies who post bad contents - usually they are serious people who sometimes make innocent mistakes in their edits. Of course some will still rant about it, but all in all it will greatly reduce the problem.

Comment: Even more: while [Decision on rejected edits should be displayed as a notification to the editor](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor) is not implemented, showing some warning *instead of* the edit link might help folks become aware of their ban (and their earlier mistakes) before actually clicking "edit". The ban is just a week; some might not notice it at all, I guess.

Comment: @Arjan didn't see that other request - thanks! Agree this would be better.

Comment: I suddenly wonder if there's any message at all; so far all questions I saw were about the missing edit link?

Comment: I don't think the group of users suggesting edits contains more newbies than the group of users asking questions, considering that in both the cases, the required reputation is 1. It is probable that first users starts asking question, and then suggesting edits, but that doesn't mean a user who cannot anymore suggests edit would not ask a question on meta, if he/she would find a link in the dialog box saying he/she cannot suggest further edits. I am not against adding the idea, though, and I welcome it.

Comment: Ah, I forgot: there is [a disabled edit link, with a tooltip](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91172/always-show-the-edit-button-on-questions/138944#138944) nowadays. Good luck adding a link to that. ;-)

Comment: @Arjan yup nice find. :) Maybe my request will also require changing that. Hmm..

Comment: Yeah, I beat you to that. But, worse, I actually once knew, as I edited it [into Jeff's more generic answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-dont-i-see-an-edit-button-under-questions/81701#81701). But well, can't remember everything! :-)

Comment: And [apparently](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140936/account-is-not-allowed-to-suggest-edits/140938#comment398389_140938) the tooltip is just *"Account is not allowed to suggest edits"*.

Comment: @Arjan well, guess it's just nice wording to "account is banned from suggesting edits" - when edit queue is full most likely tooltip will reflect that. :)