# Why am I seeing the message "Account is not allowed to suggest edits"?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a penalty for one's edit suggestion being rejected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78129/is-there-a-penalty-for-ones-edit-suggestion-being-rejected)
>   [Why is the edit button disabled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-is-the-edit-button-disabled)
>   [Account is Not Allowed to Suggest Edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140936/account-is-not-allowed-to-suggest-edits)

I have got edit link disabled and when I hover on it it shows the message that "*Account is not allowed to suggest edits*". Why am I getting this message?

> [image]

Comment: Have you had a number of suggested edits rejected recently?

Comment: @Bart would you tell me how to see this?

Comment: Check every single links here (well, the interface is not so good b/c of that): http://stackoverflow.com/users/1280616/mayank-swami?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

Comment: Go to your profile and then the activity tab. Narrow it down to suggestions. Then click on those to see whether they were accepted or rejected.

Comment: @Bart in some it was approved and in some it might be rejected or edited again than now would you tell me can i get this right again ??

Comment: If you have a number of edits rejected, you get a time-out for a week. I don't know if that's the case here, but it might be. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work

Comment: In the latest build, it seems that they remove the link to the details of each suggested edit. I have filed a bug report.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the edit button disabled?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-is-the-edit-button-disabled) and [Account is Not Allowed to Suggest Edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140936/account-is-not-allowed-to-suggest-edits).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've had an abnormally large number of your suggested edits rejected. When that happens, the system automatically prevents you from suggesting further edits for a week.

Looking though your suggestions, I think I see the problem. You've recently been suggesting quite a few edits that consist of simply applying `code-formatting` or **bolding** to text. This can be helpful when placed around sections of actual code, but when used over a large number of words in prose, it just makes posts harder to read. I'd suggest not doing that.